# Rabbitmq localhost:15672 can't login

Tags: rabbitmq, localhost

I upgrade the erlang from 21.x to 22.x and upgrade the Rabbitmq from 36.x to 37.x in my windows.
But when I upgrade down , I can't login the localhost:15672 , the page just like this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jPq5.jpg)

there is blank below the title,and the buttons can't be touched. 
Any solutions about that ?

Comment: This site is about programming problems. So you are a little bit off-topic: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic --- maybe one of the other stack exchange sites is better suited for your problem.

Comment: sorry I need use the rabbitmq client on android and the server can't work